# Get an URL parameter and print in an HTML page

Tags: java, html

There is a way to get a parameter from a url and print it in a web page? For example, `?n=john&e=john@email.it`.

I want to show the parameter `n` inside an HTML page.

Comment: you mean is get request parameter of URL?

Comment: Adjust formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this.

```js
var urlStr = "http://www.demo.com?n=john&e=john@email.it"; //window.location.href
document.write(new URL(urlStr).searchParams.get("n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

through this can get the value of after '?' :

```js
location.search.substr(1);
```

other you can split by char '&'